# Javascript - Disable ajax/force new window. (WordPress)

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I am customising the behaviour of a wordpress plugin http://shiftcontroller.com.  The plugin uses AJAX for the "creating new shift" process.

I have added profile links to a pre-existing list of staff using javascript but my links are attempting to make AJAX calls instead of opening in a new tab.

This is what I've got so far:

```
      var StaffInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.hc-sm-col.hc-sm-col-6 ul li input');
  console.log(StaffInputs);

  for (i = 0; i < StaffInputs.length; ++i) {
    console.log(StaffInputs[i].defaultValue);
    // var staffLink = document.createElement( "a", { class: "staff-profile-link", href: "http://mydomainhere.co.uk/user/"+StaffInputs[i].defaultValue } );
    var staffLink = document.createElement("a");
    staffLink.setAttribute( "class", "staff-profile-link" );
    staffLink.setAttribute( "href", "http://mydomainhere.co.uk/?author="+StaffInputs[i].defaultValue );
    staffLink.setAttribute( "target", "_blank" );
    staffLink.setAttribute( "rel", "external" );
    staffLink.setAttribute( "data-ajax", "false" );
    staffLink.innerHTML = '    <i class="icomoon icomoon-notification"></i>';
    StaffInputs[i].nextSibling.appendChild(staffLink);
  }
```

However, for some reason, my links still won't open in a new window. Is there any way I can force this by way of Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how the ajax request is being made as the plugin code is extensive and hard to understand for my level. Do you mean like this: href="javascript:my_function();" ?

Comment: Wow. That worked. Can you answer the question directly and I will choose your answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a handler directly on the `a` tag and have it stop propagation. (Assuming the AJAX request is being made by a handler that is using delegation up the DOM tree.)

```
staffLink.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```